# SQL query to add multiple values into an attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I appreciate any help. I am creating a database query and I would like to add something.
I created two tables(users&videos) and I would like to insert video_id into users table but however I would like one user to have multiple videos. For example, user_id 1 should have all three videos. Any help?

`create table users (
user_id int,
username varchar(50),
video_id int,
primary key (user_id) );`

`insert into users(user_id,username,video_id) values (1,'trex',1&2&3);` This line is incorrect.

`create table videos (
video_id int,
video_title varchar(100),
primary key (video_id) );`

`insert into videos(video_id,video_title) values (1,'Math tutor'),(2,'SQL joins'),(3,'Fastest cars');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in that case, you should normalize your table users, remove `video_id` from here and create one table to have `users to video mapping`, something like this:

```
create table user_videoes (
user_id int,
video_id int);
```

By this approach, one user can have multiple videos and one video can belong to multiple users.

Comment: Thank a lot. This is useful and much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If a video can only belong to one user then you should do it the other way around, ie. the user_id field is in the video table. That way one user can have many videos.

Comment: I have to do some multiple stuff. Like many videos belonging to a channel that is why I used user as an example. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert 1&2&3 as int on video_id

You need to insert three rows, to get three video_id's, and one for each video

```
insert into users(user_id,username,video_id) values (1,'trex',1);
insert into users(user_id,username,video_id) values (1,'trex',2);
insert into users(user_id,username,video_id) values (1,'trex',3);
```

But then, user_id can't be primary key. Use rather one id column whit autoincrement

Comment: Thank you but I did not want to repeat such values.

Comment: Well, he _could_ insert it with _Boolean_ `&`, but then he'd only be able to store 32 videos (assuming a 32-bit integer).  And it'd be a pain to get at...